# Untrusted user-agent?

Tags: user-agent

My logs recently showed the following user-agent:

samsung-gt-s5620 UNTRUSTED/1.0

Why would a user-agent have untrusted in caps in its name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly because the phone considers the browser an untrusted application.

Comment: This appears to be the case. According to [this](http://www.useragentstring.com/Chrome18.6.872.0_id_19047.php) UNTRUSTED is "Added by MIDP whenever an application is not signed" (where MIDP = Mobile Information Device Profile, I believe)

Answer (score 0):

The User-Agent is a HTTP header sent by browsers. Thus, everything can be put in it. It is a decision made by the browser manufacturer.